# Syntax | $x \in Z_{f1} \times Z_{f2} \times \cdots \times Z_{n}$

Tags: ring-theory

I want to express an integer x as an n-tuple such that the $i^{th}$ member of the tuple is $x \mod f_i$ where $f_i$ is the $i^{th}$ member of another n-tuple of integers. Also each $f_i$ is coprime to each $f_j$ where $i \neq j$.

Would I write $x \in Z_{f1} \times Z_{f2} \times \cdots \times Z_{n}$? Or what is the most concise way to express this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ define $\hat{x}=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\in \left(\mathbb{Z}/f_1\mathbb{Z}\right)\times\left(\mathbb{Z}/f_2\mathbb{Z}\right)\times\left(\mathbb{Z}/f_n\mathbb{Z}\right)$, by:$$x_i=[x],\qquad\qquad i=1,2\cdots,n.$$

Comment: What does $[x]$ denote?

Comment: It denotes the equivalence class of $x$ as an element of $\mathbb{Z}/f_i\mathbb{Z}$.  As $x_i$ is an equivalence class of integers, and $x$ is an integer, it should be clear that this is the correct interpretation.  However to be safe, it might be a good idea to add "where $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$ as an element of $\mathbb{Z}/f_i\mathbb{Z}$."